# Keras Image Preprocessing: Tuple Index Out of Range

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

The goal of the script is to use Keras' existing image preprocessing module for video data augmentation. In this prototype, a sample video is split into an array of frames and processed, where the final steps involve performing random rotations, shifts, shears, and zooms:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import random_rotation, random_shift, random_shear, random_zoom
K.set_image_dim_ordering("th")

import cv2
import numpy as np

video_file_path = "./training-data/yes/1.mov"
samples_generated_per_sample = 10
self_rows = 100
self_columns = 150
self_frames_per_sequence = 45

# haar cascades for localizing oral region
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml')

video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
success, frame = video.read()

frames = []
success = True

# convert to grayscale, localize oral region, equalize dimensions, 
# normalize pixels, equalize lengths, and accumulate valid frames 
while success:
  success, frame = video.read()
  if success:
    # convert to grayscale
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # localize single facial region
    faces_coords = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
    if len(faces_coords) == 1:
      face_x, face_y, face_w, face_h = faces_coords[0]
      frame = frame[face_y:face_y + face_h, face_x:face_x + face_w]

      # localize oral region
      mouth_coords = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
      threshold = 0
      for (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h) in mouth_coords:
        if (mouth_y > threshold):
            threshold = mouth_y
            valid_mouth_coords = (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h)
        else:
            pass
      mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h = valid_mouth_coords
      frame = frame[mouth_y:mouth_y + mouth_h, mouth_x:mouth_x + mouth_w]

      frames.append(frame)

    # ignore multiple facial region detections
    else:
        pass

# pre-pad short sequences and equalize sequence lengths
if len(frames) < self_frames_per_sequence:
    frames = [frames[0]]*(self_frames_per_sequence - len(frames)) + frames
frames = frames[0:self_frames_per_sequence]
frames = np.asarray(frames)

rotated_frames = random_rotation(frames, rg=45)
shifted_frames = random_shift(rotated_frames, wrg=0.25, hrg=0.25)
sheared_frames = random_shear(shifted_frames, intensity=0.79)
zoomed_frames = random_zoom(sheared_frames, zoom_range=(1.25, 1.25))
```

When the script is the run, the following error appears:
[image: Output Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the unequal frame dimensions. The solution was to equalize the frame dimensions first before applying transformations:

```
# pre-pad short sequences, equalize frame dimensions, and equalize sequence lengths
if len(frames) < self_frames_per_sequence:
    frames = [frames[0]]*(self_frames_per_sequence - len(frames)) + frames
frames = frames[0:self_frames_per_sequence]
frames = [cv2.resize(frame, (self_columns, self_rows)).astype('float32') for frame in frames]
frames = np.asarray(frames)

rotated_frames = random_rotation(frames, rg=45)
shifted_frames = random_shift(rotated_frames, wrg=0.25, hrg=0.25)
sheared_frames = random_shear(shifted_frames, intensity=0.79)
zoomed_frames = random_zoom(sheared_frames, zoom_range=(1.25, 1.25))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, when you say "unequal frame dimensions"? What were the dimentions before, and after your changes?

Comment: @Benjamin initially, all the frames have the same dimensions (1980 x 1080), but after applying cascade classification to localize and crop the oral region, the frames no longer have the same sizes (e.g. mouth open vs. mouth closed, at varying degrees, causing the height to range from ~85-110 and width to range from ~135-170). Resizing them to standardize their dimensions to 100x150 (rough average of their widths/heights) fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the parameters: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L25.

You are giving `frames` as a flat array, but it is expecting an array with at least three axes, so it can take `row_axis=1, col_axis=2`, by default. Either specify those parameters correctly, or provide with a correctly shaped array.

Comment: Hello @Benjamin frames is a list of 2D numpy arrays before it gets converted into a numpy array itself. Doesn't that make it a 3D tensor?

Comment: Found the problem. It was due to the unequal frame dimensions. Equalizing the frame dimensions fixes the issue. Thanks.